# Which directory to put object constructors in node / express

Tags: node.js, express

I want to create an object constructor for a new sign up within express. Where should this be located? Within the model? The controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really up to you to decide on your directory structure. Express doesn't enforce any particular structure.

That said, an object constructor clearly seems to fall into the *model* category. The model should include any data structures and logic for interacting with the database. The view is just what the user sees and interacts with, and the controller mediates between the view and the model (express *routes* would fit into this category).

For a short example using express with the sort of directory structure you seem to have, see [this](http://timstermatic.github.io/blog/2013/08/17/a-simple-mvc-framework-with-node-and-express/). Although the example uses a [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) schema, the same principle should apply if you are using an ordinary object constructor. You might also want to look at some of the [examples](https://github.com/expressjs/express/tree/master/examples) in the Express repository, including a different implementation of an [mvc pattern](https://github.com/expressjs/express/tree/master/examples/mvc).